# Using a console runner

Tags: windows

This sounds really naive but if I want to run a console application, and it provides an example like this:

Usage: gendarme [--config file] [ruleset], where these are parameters, how do I use this in Windows?

Comment: What are you asking? It's very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are encapsulated in square brackets [ ], which means that they are optional.

It is best to read the documentation of your application to see what to specify and what not,
you could also try to look for examples or guides on Google to understand more about it.

If it knows where the config is it could be as simple as:

```
gendarme
```

If it does not it could be:

```
gendarme --config C:\PathToA\File.ext
```

Or even more than that if you need to specify a ruleset...

Answer (score 0):

Start | Run | `cmd`

Will open a console window containing a command prompt. In there type the command.